# easier way to toggle a radio button with JavaScript/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I've set up radio buttons like this:

```html
<hr />
<h2>PhoneyTV Cabana</h2>
<p>
  <input type="radio" id="phoneyRadio1" value="0" onclick="toggleParticlePower(phoneyID, phoneyPowerFunction, this.value)" name="led" />Off
  <input type="radio" id="phoneyRadio2" value="1" onclick="toggleParticlePower(phoneyID, phoneyPowerFunction, this.value)" name="led" />On
</p>
```

there must be a simpler way of updating their stat than this:

```js
$.getJSON(myURL, function(data) {
  state = (parseInt(data.result) == 1)
  if (state) {
    $('#phoneyRadio1').attr('checked', false);
    $('#phoneyRadio2').attr('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('#phoneyRadio2').attr('checked', false);
    $('#phoneyRadio1').attr('checked', true);
  }
});
```

I tried just making the 'active' button highlighted, but I'm having trouble with that...

What obvious shortcut am I missing?

Comment: Checking a radio button will automatically uncheck others in the same group.

Comment: I tried your code, I tried similar approach, but I often get a bug where neither is highlighted...  Perhaps something else is interfering with this state change?  Is there a way to wrap and execute those two lines atomically?

Comment: @JimfromPrinceton You can try something like this: [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/kecce3ac/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (state) {
  $('#phoneyRadio1').attr('checked', false);
  $('#phoneyRadio2').attr('checked', true);
} else {
  $('#phoneyRadio1').attr('checked', true);
  $('#phoneyRadio2').attr('checked', false);
}
```

In the above code, if you observe closely, a simple pattern that value for `phoneyRadio1` is always opposite of condition and `phoneyRadio2` is same as condition. So it can be reduced to:

```
$('#phoneyRadio1').attr('checked', !state);
$('#phoneyRadio2').attr('checked', state);
```

Now, `state = (parseInt(data.result) == 1)` will make `state` a global variable(missing `var`). Secondly, you are converting `data.result` to int, so since you are matching same type values, you should use `===` instead of `==`.

So it would look like `var state = (parseInt(data.result) === 1)` or `var state = (+(data.result) === 1)`.

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/kecce3ac/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$.getJSON(myURL, function(data) {
  state = (parseInt(data.result) == 1)
  $('#phoneyRadio1').attr('checked', !state);
  $('#phoneyRadio2').attr('checked', state);
});
```